# "Reset" Amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I am running an EC2 server with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. But there are things that aren't working properly on it. CPAN won't install any modules, the MYSQL service keeps falling over, etc.

So I want to "factory reset" it and start all over again.

Is there anyway to do this but keeping this instance and it's elastic IP address?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Launch a new instance for the same AMI. If you are using an elastic IP address you can attach it to the new instance.

Comment: How to reset AMI?